# Python and Django IDE with remote editing?

Tags: python, django, ide

I'm looking for an IDE that will allow me to edit remote Python projects and also has decent Django support, remote command execution, and maybe remote debugging.  I've tried PyCharm and Aptana with PyDev but I'm not having much luck configuring them for remote editing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you set up PyCharm to edit remote projects?  I can mount remote directories with SSHFS and insert them into local projects, but I'd rather not.

Comment: You copy them locally and setup (auto)-deployment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have Pycharm setup on a Ubuntu 10.10.  The key is to use "sshfs" - it maps to my web-host - via ssh. Those are the pre-reqs : ssh access, sshfs. (unless you can figure out a way to map ssh to a windows shared drive).

So once ssh, sshfs are setup, I create a linux mount locally - so my webhost's directory appears locally as "/webhostx" .. From then on Pycharm (or WingIde or any editor) does not care that "/webhostx" is really a remote folder mounted locally.

If all else fails there's always Emacs (everything included :-) ).

Pycharm also has a remote debugging feature - I am in the process of testing it with my host (webfaction).

Comment: be careful using pycharm and sshfs with a mercurial project. I've had major issues with corrupted repos

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has [tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) for remote editing on top of ssh, ftp or other protocols(works out of the box). [nxhtml](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs) has support for editing Django templates (needs setup). I don't know about remote debugging. I've never done that.

Of course, Emacs is a lifestyle rather than an editor as most of its users will tell you so be warned.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WingIDE](http://www.wingware.com).